# compilation Error CS0176 (static member cannot be accessed) on non static method

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

my problem is the following :

when I try to compile my c# apps it run into this exception :

> Static member 'ResponseManager.manage(Response)' cannot be accessed
>   with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

on this

```
ResponseManager responseManager = new ResponseManager();
responseManager.manage(response);
```

As you can see I'm using a new instance of the ResponseManager.

here is his "manage" method's declaration :

`public void manage(Response response)`

I checked in project and it's the only method with this name, she's not static and ResponseManager don't have any static fields/methods and yet it won't compile.

When i try to rename my method everywhere in my code (declaration and usage) I get the following error :

> ResponseManager does not contain a definition for 'sometest' and no
>   extension method 'sometest' accepting a first argument of type
>   'ResponseManager ' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

I hope I provided enought information to help me resolve this.
Many thanks !

---

Edit :

```
public class ResponseManager
{

    TransactionDAO transactionDAO = new TransactionDAO();
    LignesDAO ligneDAO = new LignesDAO();
    SimDAO simDAO = new SimDAO();
    MailSender mailSender = new MailSender();
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    ApplicationDAO appDAO = new ApplicationDAO();


    //RENAME !!!!!!!!  
    public void manage(Response response)
    {

        if (response.responseStatus.status == "SUCCESS")
        {
            transactionDAO.updateTransactionById(response.header.transactionId, response.responseStatus.status);

            string type = transactionDAO.getTransactionTypeById(response.header.transactionId);

            if(type != null) { 

                switch (type) {
                    case "activate":
                        ligneDAO.setActivatedSim(response.simIdendity.simSerial);
                        //simDAO.setActivatedSim(response.simIdendity.simSerial);


                        break;
                    case "suspend":
                        ligneDAO.setSuspendedSim(response.simIdendity.simSerial);
                        //simDAO.setSuspendedSim(response.simIdendity.simSerial);


                        break;
                    case "reactivate":
                        ligneDAO.setActivatedSim(response.simIdendity.simSerial);
                        //simDAO.setActivatedSim(response.simIdendity.simSerial);

                        break;
                    case "detail-subscription":

                        break;
                    case "detail-sim":
                        //Mapping between Response and Sim classes


                        break;
                    case "bar" :

                        break;
                    case "unbar" :

                        break;
                }
            }

            int appId = transactionDAO.getIdAppFromTransactionId(response.header.transactionId);

            string url = appDAO.getUrlFromAppId(appId);

            httpClient.send(null, url);

        }
        else 
        {
            transactionDAO.updateTransactionById(response.header.transactionId, response.responseStatus.status, response.responseStatus.errorCode);

            string type = transactionDAO.getTransactionTypeById(response.header.transactionId);

            mailSender.createTransatelProvisionningErrorMail(response.header.transactionId, response.simIdendity.simSerial, response.simIdendity.msisdn, type, response.responseStatus.errorCode, response.responseStatus.reason);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide more code? At least ResponseManager class.

Comment: Do you have another ResponseManager class in your solution? If you select the line `responseManager.manage(response);` and put the cursor on manage and F12. Does it go to the class and method you expect?

Comment: @Stuart it's the only one with this name and this method (and yup it goes to the right method)

Comment: Tried cleaning solution, deleting all obj folders?

Comment: @Stuart I tried an automatic cleaning, does it delete all obj folders automatically ?

Comment: @Stuart I deleted obj and bin folder manually and regenerated the solution and it worked (you can post your comment as a solution so that i validate it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing a clean solution. Build > Clean Solution.

You can also try deleting all obj folders in your solution and rebuilding solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the problem is not with your code than try Unloading and Reloading the project or restarting VS2017. It solves the problem sometimes. And please provide RespnseManager's Code.

Comment: I've already try to reboot my computer and started it with Rider (jetbrain's C# ide)

Comment: On the basis of the information provided, I think it should work just fine. Is there any other project reference within the solution which may contain another ResponseManager class?

Comment: manually cleaning the solution just did the job, thanks thought

Comment: You're Welcome! 